# Customize netbeans rails module

Tags: plugins, netbeans, ruby, rails

The Netbeans rails plugin has a simple a project structure:

[image]

However, I have encountered the following problems:

1. I cant access `config.ru` file
2. I cant access app/uploaders dir (carrierwave gem)

What should I do? How do I customize this plugin?